# Нужно ли добавлять пагинацию в данной ситуации?

Tags: html, производительность

Есть файл `index.html` в него регулярно добавляются посты(статьи) подобного вида(через админку), только текст и ничего больше.

```
<div class='content_post'>
  <header><h1>Title</h1><header>
  <div class='post_body'>
     Text
  </div>
<div>
```

`content_post` дублируется много раз, меняется только текст и `index.html` разрастается кол-во строк около 800+. Вопрос будет ли нагрузка на сервер из-за этого? Просто я видел на некоторых сайтах используют пагинацию и статьи грузятся по определенному кол-ву, 5 загрузилось потом еще 5 и т.д. Я бы не хотел ее добавлять просто из-за внешнего вида и так все устраивает, интересует одно, будет ли критично если в моем `html` шаблоне будет много `content_post` и повлияет ли это на производительность? Либо лучше добавить пагинацию? И код будет разрастаться в зависимости от пагинации. Не знаю правильно ли я разъяснил. Также хочу сказать, что посты хранятся в БД и достаются они от туда и рендерятся в шаблон `html` единственную страницу блога `index.html`

Comment: Попробуйте и измерьте производительность

Comment: да по барабану на сервер. производительность браузера страдает а в итоге, самая важный фактор, который нельзя терять --- пользователь. Ведь это всё нужно отрендерить, память + процессор. Однозначно -- пагинация нужна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пагинция нужна хотя бы потому, что страница будет легче, и она быстрее грузиться у клиента. Скорость загрузки важна в наше время.
Нагрузка на базу тоже уменьшится, и генерация контента опять же только ускорится.